# Android Studio 1.0.1 add external libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, libs

I have just downloaded Android Studio 1.0.1 and this is the new project structure

[image]

and when i see it in the explorer there is a empty libs folder
[image]

i want to import 3 external libraries i have, which i want to use.

build.gradle has already defined this

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

but when i copy my libraries in libs folder my project still dont recognize it,
how do i make use of the libs folder and copy my libraries in this folders and use it?
any help?

Edit:
it was a simple question, how to add libraries to project in Android Studio
like we do in eclipse, for eg i have a library project(a folder, not a jar!).
in my case i have a library project 'viewPagerIndicator' (again a Library folder, not a jar!) i have to add it to my project like i use to do it with eclipse by importing project, right click->properties->android->Library->add-> select the library project

PS: i have found the answer now.
suppose my library project name is 'viewPagerIndicator'
- Copy library project on root of my Android Studio Project
- Under build.gradle(under your Android Studio Project folder) write this under dependencies 
      compile project(':viewPagerIndicator')
- include it in settings.gradle, write:
      include ':viewPagerIndicator'
- Sync project with gradle files

this is how project structure look like now:

[image]

so sorry that admins stopping the question without understanding it.

Comment: do you want to add .jar ?

Comment: I did as you had instructed. But I end up with this error

`Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First you have to add library project (module) in Android Studio

```
File -> Import Module
```

To add library project (module) in build path, click

```
File -> Project Structure
```

On the left hand side click on

```
app -> Dependencies tab -> green + button -> Module dependency
```

Now select the library project you already added.

For more details refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16639227/3843374)

Comment: My project correpted thanks :) Error:(64, 0) No such property: sonatypeUsername for class: org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated <a href="openFile">Open File</a>

Answer (score 1):

In My Case to add external library project into android studio 1.1.0

**step-1 :** File -> Import Module -> set path for library project

**step-2 :** Set ***dependencies{}*** in main projects's ***build.gradle*** like,

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile project(':slidingMenu')
    compile project(':SkyconsLibrary')
}
```