# Android Studio - Add dependency to all modules

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies, build.gradle

I have read tons of posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851230/android-gradle-build-error9-0-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-compile), but they only tell you that you should not add dependencies to the project root `build.gradle`, which I know.
My situation is: I have a lot of modules that all need the same library. All of them, so I need to configure all of them to have the same library. Is it possible to add this somehow to the root `build.gradle` or I have add to each project `build.gradle` the dependency?

Comment: You can use subprojects https://proandroiddev.com/reducing-boilerplate-in-gradle-multi-module-projects-2ff2dde5bf95

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do something like this.
It doesn't mean to add a dependency for all modules, but in this way you can **centralize** a dependency.

In top-level `build.gradle`

```
    ext {
        //Version
        supportLibrary = '23.0.1'

        //Support Libraries dependencies
        supportDependencies = [
                appCompat     : "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibrary}",
                design        : "com.android.support:design:${supportLibrary}",
        ]
    }
```

In each module add to `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    //......
    compile supportDependencies.appCompat
    compile supportDependencies.design
}
```

In this way, when you have to update the library, you can simply change only the top-level file.

Comment: Thanks for this solution! Really useful!

Answer (score 4):

I know the question is a bit old but I started using this which I think would be cleaner if you do not care about what libraries being injected into your module.

root `build.gradle`

```
ext {
    commonDependencies = [
            // Layout Libraries
            constraintLayoutApi     : "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$constraintlayout_version",
            materialApi             : "com.google.android.material:material:$material_version",
            flexboxApi              : "com.google.android:flexbox:$flexbox_version",

            // Image library (Picasso is alternative)
            glideImpl               : "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version",
            glideCompilerAnno       : "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glide_version",

            // Network library (Volley is alternative)
            retrofitImpl            : "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version",
            retrofitJacksonImpl     : "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:$retrofit_version",
            retrofitScalarsImpl     : "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:$retrofit_version",
            retrofitJava8Impl       : "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-java8:$retrofit_version",

            // Dependency Injection
            daggerImpl              : "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version",
            daggerCompilerAnno      : "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version",
            // we add this so we can use the android support libraries
            daggerAndroidSupportImpl: "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$dagger_version",
            daggerProcessorAnno     : "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger_version"
    ]
}
```

and in app `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    api "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$app_compact_version"
    api "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$play_service_version"

    commonDependencies.each { key, value ->
        if (key.endsWith('Anno')) {
            annotationProcessor value
        } else if (key.endsWith('Impl')) {
            implementation value
        } else if (key.endsWith('Api')) {
            api value
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I am checking for API, Implementation, and Annotation by the suffix of the key in the root gradle file.

Comment: It helps me. Thanks! Just for others' reference: `root build.gradle` means the `build.gradle` of the Android Project (others are Module.

Comment: How will Gradle know when to sync and when not to in case you have added an extra dependency in the `ext` list

Comment: Basically it is not automatic at least I didn't work on it to become automatic but it is simple refresh button in the intellij that you can do whenever you add one dependency

Answer (score 0):

1. First you have to add chart library project (module) in Android Studio (your current workspace)
   File -> Import Module
2. To add library project (module) in build path, click
   File -> Project Structure
3. On the left hand side click on
   app -> Dependencies tab -> green + button -> Module dependency
   Now select the library project you already added.
   For more details refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541783/android-studio-1-0-1-add-external-libraries)

Comment: I know how to add a dependency to my project. I want to know if it's possible to (yes, I'm quoting myself) `add this somehow to the root build.gradle or do I have add to each project build.gradle the dependency?`

Comment: You have to add dependency for all library